# CSS Best Practices: Classes for all elements or styling by parent class?

Tags: css

So, I was wondering about the following: I have some main content div and a sidebar div and the CSS looks as follows:

```
.main{
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px 
}
.sidebar{
 width: 100px;
 height: 300px;
}
```

I will not include now all the floating properties, since I am only interested in the following:
If I have a p element in both of them and I want them to have different styles, shall I give the paragraphs different classes or shall I define the style for them like this:

```
.main p{
 color: blue;
 text-align: right;
 font-family: ...
}
```

And then for .sidebar p I would define something else...
The alternative would be to define a class p.myclass and define the style there.
I am trying to understand what a better practice is. Obviously I need less markup if I have 30 p elements in one of the elements with the first method, since I would have to give them all a class. On the other hand, I create CSS that I can only "use" for that parent element, instead of having a general definition that I can apply in more places in the site...
I noticed that in a lot of "big" websites, almost every single html element has its own class...
Any ideas?

Comment: BEM and OOCSS were created with the latter option in mind. They scale, they're really useful for big projects. For small projects, whatever fits your constraints, your skills, those of your team, client, history and future of this project, etc (a.k.a. *it depends©*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely go ahead with the containment selector in the case you give. Fewer spurious classes in the markup is easier to maintain, and the rule ‘.main p’ says clearly what it does. Use your judgement to whether more complicated cases are still clear.

Note that ‘.main p’ selects all descendent paragraphs and not just direct children, which may or may not be what you want; accidentally-nested descendant matches are a potential source of bugs (especially for cumulative properties like relative font size). If you want only children to be selected you need ‘.main>p’, which unfortunately does not work in IE6.

This is one reason why many sites go crazy with the classnames: the more involved selectors that could otherwise be used to pick out elements without a classname, tend not to work in IE.

Comment: And of course putting any styling common to all <p> tags in a seperate p{} section of your CSS will reduce duplicated code. I guess you could argue it increases maintenance effort, though.

Comment: While I feel this is the best practice, Google has said recently that class selectors are faster for the browser, since with generic element descendant selectors, the browser first finds all `p` elements, then searches upwards through the DOM tree to find a parent class.

Answer (score 3):

I vote for `.main p` and `.sidebar p` because:

- It most clearly expresses your intention, as you're expressing it in English
- It reduces the number of explicit classes you need in your HTML
- If you change your mind later and want an explicit paragraph class with that style you can just add it: `.main p, p.foo`

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion using nested selectors [ parent child relations ] will be harder to read and maintainable.

Evdn if the design changes in a frequent manner CSS should be less affected by that. So styling individual element will be easier in the case of maintainability.

If the element is going to exist in a predictable location then you can style it based on a parent element.

Comment: Disagree - this just discards one of the benefits of CSS, namely the ease of making consistent styles with less code. If you have to manually add a specific class to all elements in a part of your page, what's the difference between that and the old FONT and CENTER tags? If a sidebar needs to style its paragraphs differently, then CSS has very good syntax to solve exactly that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The major drawback of styling by class on each individual element is the bloat: If you have many of these elements, the CSS attributes will become a noticeable percentage of the transferred bytes. Especially for large documents, saving a couple of KB in the download can count. Even more so with AJAX requests or IE where parsing `innerHTML` is extremely slow.

Comment: This is what I am afraid of. So, I guess equilibrating both methods, dependent on the needs would be ok. Just deciding where to do what is the difficult part. Especially in an evolving project... Thanks for the great answers!